# Need help parsing XML file for Twitter Oauth

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I've written a twitter desktop app that basically just lets me post tweets and pics... nothing fancy.

I've got everything working but this last part of persisting a config file (which is the following XML generated by my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Twitterer><config id="1"><accessToken>ENDLESS-STRING-OF-CHARACTERS</accessToken><accessTokenSecret>ANOTHER-ENDLESS-STRING-OF-CHARACTERS</accessTokenSecret></config></Twitterer>
```

What I need to do is just set the accessToken & accessTokenSecret variables. The filename is config.xml.

I've been looking at a lot of examples on the net, but can't seem to wrap my head around only getting two values from the file, which shouldn't need a loop.

This is as far as I've gotten on this last piece of my puzzle:

```
try {
        File fXmlFile = new File(this.getFileName());
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("config");
        int numberOfConfigs = nList.getLength();

        // GET THE TWO VARIABLES HERE

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

If anyone can help me just read those two tags into their corresponding variables I would be quite appreciative. I can handle the rest of the Authorization after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need to do is just set the accessToken & accessTokenSecret variables

A simple code using `getElementsByTagName()` method

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();   
root.getElementsByTagName("accessToken").item(0).getTextContent()
root.getElementsByTagName("accessTokenSecret").item(0).getTextContent()
```

output:

```
ENDLESS-STRING-OF-CHARACTERS
ANOTHER-ENDLESS-STRING-OF-CHARACTERS
```

---

OR try as child node of `config` tag

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList configNodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("config");
NodeList nodeList = ((Node) configNodeList.item(0)).getChildNodes();
System.out.println(nodeList.item(0).getTextContent());
System.out.println(nodeList.item(1).getTextContent());
```

Comment: Worked quite well :-)